# Can you plot a location on the UWP Map Control with an altitude?

Tags: uwp

I have a UWP app with a MapControl and I draw MapIcons on the map for specific locations. But can I also give them an altitude?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to make the icon larger?

Answer (score 0):

In order to position elements at specific locations on the map, one would use the MapControl.Location Attached property:

```
<Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/PinStore.png" Width="30"
       maps:MapControl.Location="{x:Bind Location}"
       maps:MapControl.NormalizedAnchorPoint="{x:Bind Anchor}"/>
```

I haven't checked myself but, given that the MapControl.Location property is of type `Geopoint` and that `Geopoint` supports an altitude value and reference system I would assume that this would work. You would probably need to display your map in 3D Mode (use the `Style` property of the MapControl) and Tilted (use the 'DesiredPitch` property on the MapControl) so that altitude "makes sense" though.

Answer (score 0):

When drawing a `MapIcon` on the map, you need to pass a `Geopoint`. This can be constructed via a `BasicGeoposition` which contains a `Altitude` property:

```
new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition 
{ 
  Latitude  = 52.181427, 
  Longitude = 5.399780,
  Altitude  = 10 //unit: meters
});
```

Using the great 3D features of the UWP MapControl you can see your MapIcons floating around. Feel free to have a look at this article ["Windows 10 maps part 5 - styles and 3D" by Joost van Schaik](http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.de/2015/09/windows-10-maps-part-5-styles-and-3d.html).